# What is the proper way to record when an item is captured?

Tags: org-mode

I would like org-capture template to capture time at creation so I can use this recorded time later for routine cleaning of old tasks.

Currently I use this template with the `%t` expansion.

```
(setq org-capture-templates
  '(("p" "PRIVAT-TODO" entry (file+headline "/home/max/org/organizer.org" "Private")
     "* TODO %? %^g\n %t")))
```

But org uses timestamp to schedule and not for recording capture time.

What is the proper way to record when an item was captured?

How can I then us the time to sort in todo list views.

Comment: What is a todo list view?  Is that the master `org-mode` file with all of your tasks/events?  Is it a custom view in the `*Org Agenda*` buffer?  Does the function `org-sort-entries` help any with respect to sorting the master `org-mode` file (it operates on a main heading, or on a selected region)?

Comment: `org-capture-tamplates` can accept a function to locate a `target`, so if the default *append* or the optional `:prepend` of the new capture item will not suffice, then a function can be crafted.  I would suggest relying upon `org-sort-entries` and just *append* or `:prepend` the new capture item, but the choice is yours.  If you need a special function, then consider posting a new question with details regarding what it is that you expect as a result.

Comment: To access the todo list view type `C-c a t` assuming you bound `org-agenda` to `C-c a`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refer to the documentation for `org-capture-templates` (try `C-h v org-capture-templates`) for all the supported %-escapes. The relevant bit for your question:

```
  %t          Time stamp, date only.
  %T          Time stamp with date and time.
  %u, %U      Like the above, but inactive time stamps.
```

You want to use `%u` rather than `%t` if you want the time stamp to be inactive.

See the [Org manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Timestamps.html#Timestamps) for more detail on the the different kinds of time stamps. A plain time stamp (`%t`) affects how Org displays the entry in agenda views, while an inactive time stamp (`%u`) does not.

Comment: I overlooked the `%u`. Thank you